# Is there an element or not?

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
const arrow = document.querySelector("#arrow");
const callAllPie = document.querySelector(".allPie");

eventList();
function eventList(e) {
  arrow.addEventListener("click", showSkills);
}

// function showSkills() {
//   const pie = document.createElement("div");
//   pie.classList.add("pie1");

//   callAllPie.appendChild(pie);

//   const rightDiv = document.createElement("div");
//   rightDiv.classList.add("slice-right1");

//   const leftDiv = document.createElement("div");
//   leftDiv.classList.add("slice-left1");

//   const percentDiv = document.createElement("div");
//   percentDiv.classList.add("percent1");

//   const numberDiv = document.createElement("div");
//   numberDiv.classList.add("number1");
//   numberDiv.innerHTML = "%99";

//   const nameDiv = document.createElement("div");
//   nameDiv.classList.add("name1");
//   nameDiv.innerHTML = "HTML";

//   pie.appendChild(rightDiv);
//   pie.appendChild(leftDiv);
//   pie.appendChild(percentDiv);
//   percentDiv.appendChild(numberDiv);
//   percentDiv.appendChild(nameDiv);
//   callAllPie.appendChild(pie);
// }
function showSkills() {
  for (let element = callAllPie; element < 5; element++) {
    console.log(element);
  }
}
```

I'm trying to create a loop. If there is no element in the allPie div, I want to add the pie div I created and I want to end it when it reaches 4, how do I do it? I'm a beginner in javascript so if you can help I'd appreciate it

Comment: Hi! Please read [the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) first. Well you are trying to loop through HTML elements and in the loop you check for `element < 5`. Why do you suspect this would work? HTML elements are not numbers. Just have a counter variable you increase within the for loop and `break` when the loop output five elements. You can also manipulate the list of elements to only contain 5 elements. Either way, just try a solution out.

Comment: @PeterKrebs function showSkills() { let element = callAllPie; for (let i = 0, n = 4; i < n; i++) { //created divs } } I fix that that way but how I do break when i = n ?

Comment: Why would you want to break it - the four loop already runs 4 times. But you would write `if (i >= n) { break; }`. Just do some JavaScript tutorials they teach you how to handle loops and conditions and stuff.